# Dynamic SQL mistakenly looks for table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql

my code accepts table name parameters and my dynamic code is supposed to query a table. I consistently get the error: @sourcetbl variable must be declared. After a lot of troubleshooting, I realized why I get error. SQL keeps assuming that I must pass on a table parameter. But I don't need/want table param. I have string for a table and I want it to query the table.

My code:

```
DECLARE @DBname AS VARCHAR(30), @TblSchema AS VARCHAR(4) , @TblName AS VARCHAR(30), @LoadDate as INT
SET @DBname='Test'
SET @TblName='myTable'
SET @TblSchema='dbo' 

DECLARE @Tblnamestring AS VARCHAR(100) 

SET @Tblnamestring =' ' + @DBname + '.' + @TblSchema+ '.' + @TblName

SET @SQLCodes= N'
; WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT *
            FROM QUOTENAME(@dynamicTblName) S
            WHERE 
                S.Loaddate > ''@Loaddate''
        ) 
        SELECT * FROM CTE'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
    @STMT=@SQLCodes,
    @PARAMS=N'@dynamicTblName AS VARCHAR(100)',
    @dynamicTblName=@Tblnamestring;
```

I constantly get the error that my variable (@dynamicTblName) is not defined. So here is what I tried:

1. I tried adding QUOTENAME beside it.
2. I tried using EXEC as follow

```
    SET @SQLCodes= N'
    ; WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT *
                FROM QUOTENAME(@Tblnamestring) S
                WHERE 
    S.Loaddate > '@Loaddate'
            ) 
            SELECT * FROM CTE'
    
    EXEC (@SQLCodes)
```

3. Then I just got rid of `SP_EXECUTESQL`'s other params. And I just ran it without those.
4. I ran `SP_EXECUTESQL` with `@Tblnamestring` being defined outside.

None of these work. SQL Expects a table variable. But I am just giving a string that I need it to query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
DECLARE @Tblnamestring AS VARCHAR(100) 

SET @Tblnamestring =' ' + @DBname + '.' + @TblSchema+ '.' + @TblName

SET @SQLCodes = N'
    ; WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM QUOTENAME(@dynamicTblName) S
        WHERE S.Loaddate > @Loaddate
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM CTE'
```

Should be this:

```
DECLARE @Tblnamestring AS VARCHAR(100);

SET @Tblnamestring = QUOTENAME(@DBname) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TblSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TblName);

SET @SQLCodes = N'
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM ' + @dynamicTblName + ' S
        WHERE S.Loaddate > @Loaddate
    ) 
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE;';
```

The entire point of using dynamic SQL is to insert the table name into the SQL, giving a string which can be run as static SQL :)

And this:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
    @STMT = @SQLCodes,
    @PARAMS = N'@dynamicTblName AS VARCHAR(100)',
    @dynamicTblName = @Tblnamestring;
```

Should be:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
    @STMT = @SQLCodes,
    @PARAMS = N'@Loaddate AS INT',
    @Loaddate = @Loaddate;
```

Note the semi-colon is a statement terminator. Many people put it before `WITH` because they aren't terminating their statements correctly since SQL Server is sometimes forgiving.

Comment: this took 4 hours of my time today. Thanks

Comment: just one question: would you use SP_EXECUTESQL with those params or no, without those params? Thanks so much

Comment: Use SP_EXECUTESQL for your @loaddate parameter.